# Set default value for Bindy field

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

I'm generating a large .CSV file defined by a Bindy model. Not all fields are filled so I need sometimes a default value but I don't find a parameter to define this.

```
<!-- Bindy data format -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-bindy</artifactId>
        <!--use of ${camel-version} ?-->
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

...

```
@DataField(pos = 9, defaultValue = "0")  String von; -- error java:cannot find method defaultValue()
@DataField(pos = 10, defaultValue = "0")  Integer absolut;-- error java:cannot find method defaultValue()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2.9.2 of `camel-bindy` does not yet support the `defaultValue` attribute. If possible, use a more recent version >= 2.10.0.